# process.exit for express keeps restarting

Tags: node.js, express

When trying to programmatically use `process.exit` to kill my express server alongside with `server.close()` my server keeps restarting in my command line after `process.exit`.

Without it, `close()` makes sure the server is not responding to HTTP requests.

Any ideas for how to force kill it?

Comment: If you run nodejs shell and type here `process.exit()` - nodejs shell will exit, so we need more details about your code or you should tell us about the way you run your script (maybe you use nodejs forever (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and it restarts your script. Tell us more details.